# Accessing part of dictionary item

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

I am trying to gain information about all of the different cyclone seasons in a dataset at the same time. So far I have created a dictionary with the following:

```
#Getting number of storms; total and in each season
season = dict()

for year in range(1970, 2020):
    season[year] = ibtracs_all.get_season(year)

print("Number of seasons:")
print(len(season))
```

Which gets me a dictionary with the key for each item being the respective year (i.e. 1970).

Each item contains the following information when I print the dictionary as a result of the tropycal module function 'get_season':

```
Season Summary:
    Total Storms:      13
    Named Storms:      0
    Hurricanes:        0
    Major Hurricanes:  0
    Season ACE:        0.0
More Information:
    year:          1970
    basin:         south_indian
    source_basin:  south_indian
    source:        ibtracs
    source_info:   Joint Typhoon Warning Center (unofficial), 1971: <tropycal.tracks.Season>
```

How can I determine how many storms (Total Storms) there are in each season from this dictionary? I imagine some kind of additional loop through the dictionary but am unsure.

UPDATE: I have tried the following which only results in error:

```
x = season[year]['season_summary']['total_storms']
```

Comment: ibtracs_all is my dataset

Comment: to access the total storm info from the season dictionary you can use ```season[year]['season_sumary']['total_storms']```

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: ```year``` is a int from the loop ```for year in range(1970, 2020)```.

if I understood correctly, you are just trying to access the total storms info from the dict, right?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a list with the total number of storms for each season (year)

Comment: Well, you have to know exactly what the dictionary key names are.  Have you printed `season[2020]` to make sure you have the key spelled right?

Comment: Hmm. maybe this is the problem, I get an error when I tried to print season[2020]

Comment: But what would the key names be other than this?

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: The error is KeyError: 2020